# How do I view the OS installation date on Linux

Tags: terminal

On Windows, I can type 'systeminfo' into the command line to view stats like the OS install date.

How do I do this on Linux (Ubuntu 11.10 to be specific)?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From AskUbuntu: [How can I tell what date Ubuntu was installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-what-date-ubuntu-was-installed)

1. [Check the installer logs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365) and dates at:
   `/var/log/installer`
2. [If you use ext2/ext3/ext4](https://askubuntu.com/a/1843) and formatted the disk when you installed you can do:
   `sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created:'`

Answer (score 0):

For my Linux Mint system the following worked:

```bash
    sudo grep 'RTC time' /var/log/installer/syslog
```

The problem was my syslog didn't show years in the time stamps.